# Can we define the $L^2$ norm for a vector field $F: \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be open and suppose we have a measurable vector field $F : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ (we consider both the domain $\Omega$ and range $\mathbb{R}^d$ with Lebesgue measure).

Is there a widely used notion of an $L^2$ norm for this vector field $F$? I know that, if the range is just $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^d$, then of course the $L^2$ norm is simply

$$\left( \int_{\Omega} |F|^2 dm \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

This question has come up for me because I'm reading over a paper that keeps using the notation $||F||_{(L^2(\Omega))^d}$ where $F$ is $C^\infty$ from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$. But I'm not sure what this norm is exactly. Could it just be that the that we are integrating $|F|^2$ again? Only this time, we would need $|\cdot|$ to be the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$ instead of the absolute value function.

Explanations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a vector-valued function like $F(x) = (f_1(x),...,f_n(x))$ then you can use the vector norm $|F(x)| = (f_1(x)^2 + ... + f_n(x)^2)^{1 \over 2}$, so that $||F||_{L^2(\Omega)} = (\int_{\Omega}|F(x)|^2)^{1 \over 2}$. This is a special case of defining $L^p$ norms for functions from ${\bf R}^n$ (or any measure space) to a Banach space. Here the Banach space is just ${\bf R}^n$.